# Storing Friend Relationships in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering what the best way of storing friend relationship data using MongoDB is?

Coming from mysql I had a separate table with friend relationships that had two foreign keys, each pointing to a friend in the "friendship" however, with MongoDB its possible to have arrays of references or even embedded documents..so whats the best way to store these relationships

Immediate first reaction was that I'd store an array of friend object ids in each user, however, that troubles me, because then, in order to remove a "friendship" I would have to do deletes on both friend's documents whereas if I stored the relationship in a separate collection (a la SQL) i could remove or add a relationship by just modifying one collection.

Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing is much more suited to a traditions RDBMS rather than a schema less offering. It would be much easier if you used an RDBMS. Any particular reason you chose mongo?

Comment: Hi John, for friends, I definitely agree. I chose Mongo because of the non-structured data I'd be storing related to the friends. In particular, things like tagging and the ability to embed arrays/references in one field was really cool too for stuff like storing comments etc.

Comment: I know you probably have your heart set on MongoDB (I love it myself), but you probably want a graph database for this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Keeping a list of `friend_ids` in a user, is what I'll recommend. Few reasons,

1.You query a user, and you have list of all friends upfront available.

2.The requests (pending, accepted) can be handled as well, by seeing that a respective ids should be present in both the user's friends list. So, I can get list of actual and accepted friends by querying

```
my_id, my_friend_ids = user._id, user.friend_ids
my_friends = db.users.find({'_id':{'$in': my_friend_ids}, 'friend_ids': my_id})
```

Yes, while removing a friendship, you have to `$pull` from friend-list of both the users, but frequency of that would be much less. But you query less in getting the friend-list, which would be used frequently.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll go with that for now..it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent answer, ..."but frequency for that would be much less"...

Well, explained..thanks!!

Comment: @simplyharsh which one do you suggest embedmany or reference many?

Comment: When removing friendships though, how could you guarantee
 that they are both removed from both users. For example if you remove a friend from user 1 and the system crashes, there will be inconsistent data as user 2 would still have user 1 as their friend?

Comment: @user2924127 how about when the server starts up, it cleans up the tables to see who is friend with who ? or the removing of one friend's request should be atomic but that depends on your implementation

Comment: @AndyTsen  Suppose I am showing the list of the users then how would I show the button for `Add Friend` in front of each user... How do I query for that?

Comment: @simplyharsh pls reply to my comment

Comment: If you want to show "Add Friend" against all user who have sent you a friend request and are not a friend, you can query `db.users.find({'_id':{'$nin': my_friend_ids, 'friend_ids': my_id}})`. You can leave out the second filter, if you want to show all users who are not your friend.

Comment: @simplyharsh What about when a users has so many friends that the user document has reached the max document size of 16MB? I know that would be a lot of friends, but it is a possibility.

Comment: @Fluinc I understand what you are saying. if we are only storing 12-byte bson objectid, one document can store like 1.3 million friends? And if I have many of such popular users, I would put them into an intermediary map collection and not in users collection.

Comment: I guess there are some problems with this too. For example, what if we want to see who has followed this particular user? Then we should have an list of user-ids that follow this user too which makes a big object. Meanwhile, if we do this, we should insert into two arrays when we are following someone: 1. following list of person who is following X. 2. Followers list of X. And what if you simply need a boolean to say if X follows Y? Then you need to see if Y exists in followings list of X which is slower query than just simply doing it relationaly.