# Can a value in AWS DynamoDB point to value in different table?

Tags: database, database-design, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

First off, I have very minimal experience with servers and databases (I have only used it once in my entire life and only beginning to learn) and this would not exactly be a "code" question strictly speaking because it is a question concerning a concept regarding DynamoDB.. But here it is because I cannot find answer to it no matter how much I search!

I am trying to make an application where users can see if their friends are "online" or not. There will be a table that keeps track of the users who are online and offline like this:

```
user_id | online
1       | O
2       | X
3       | O
```

and when user_id 1 who has friends 2 & 3 "refreshes", 1 would be able to see that 2 is offline and 3 is online. This would normally be done by batch_get in dynamodb, but each item I read would count as one unit, meaning if user1 had 20 friends, one refresh would use up 20 read units. To me, that would cost too much, and I thought that if I made a table for each user that would hold list of their friends that shows whether they are online or not, each refresh would cost only one read unit.

```
user_id | friends_on_off_line
1       | {2:X, 3:O}
2       | {1:O}
3       | {1:O}
```

However, the values in the list would have to be a "pointer" to the first table, because I cannot update the value everytime someone goes online or offline (if 1 went offline, I would have to write 1 as offline to both tables, and in second table, write it twice, using 3 write units which would end up costing even more)
So I am trying to make it so that in second table, values would point to the first table that would read whether they are online/offline and return the values as a list using only 1 read unit: like this

```
user_id | friends_on_off_line
1       | {pointer_to_2.online , pointer_to_3.online}
2       | {pointer_to_1.online}
3       | {pointer_to_1.online}
```

Is this possible in DynamoDB? If not, which service should I use and how can I make it possible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DynamoDB is the right tool for this kind of job.

SQL databases (Mysql/PostgreSQL) both have easy designs - just use joins (pointers).

You can also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183147/storing-friend-relationships-in-mongodb) regarding this area for MongoDB.

What you should ask yourself is what are the most common questions the database needs to answer and what is the update / read rate. This questions usually navigate you to the right direction when picking up a database.

Comment: argh so impossible on dynamodb right...? Do you have any suggestions on which db to look at? I really want to spend minimum time working on the server / db end... Thanks for the help!

Comment: IMO go with the simplest MySQL / PostgreSQL you can.

Comment: Did you actually calculate the cost? I think you're getting stuck on the fact that Dynamo incrementally increases costs with more I/O per second. If you actually figure out how many i/o it would be, you could come up with more useful estimate. I have come 360 on Dynamo - put it in Dynamo, for the infinite scalability and ease of operations, only put it elsewhere if the data model is too complex. This is not too complex.