# update all contact lists when some user is deleted in meteor mongdb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, atomic

We are developing a simple feature of contact list (which is a simple version of friend list ).

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183147/storing-friend-relationships-in-mongodb) , I store contact_ids in contacts of each user so that userA can:

1. Add user (s) to his contacts by

   Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $push : {contacts:  newId});
2. Remove

   Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $pull : {contacts: existingId });

Now what to do if userB decides to delete his account? Loop through almost a million users to pull userB id from contacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull from all the accounts that contain that contact in one mongo update with:

```
Meteor.users.update({contacts: existingId},{$pull: {contacts: existingId}},{multi: true});
```

Comment: hey , it works in mongodb explorer ! And wow, nice love it, the syntax is different than SQL but at the end, the logic is still search and replace