# How to create efficient following - follower mechanism in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a Node.js application, with a simple follow mechanism (which allows a user to get the latest articles for those he/she follows).

I implemented this, I creating an array called followers, containing the userIDs of all users following a particular user. To get the news feed, I simply forEach in every user's followers array, to find which of them contains logged in user's id. If it is found, all the posts of those users should be retrieved in JSON format. This works for now, but I believe as many more users sign up, fetching the feed will become a more cumbersome task, slowing down the feed page's loading.

What is the best way to correct this problem, and structure the following mechanism?

N.B.: My app uses Express, Mongoose and PUG for templating.

Comment: Followers and followings is somewhat similar to friends mechanism... You can follow my this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363220/model-for-friends-schema-in-mongoose/50780844#50780844

Comment: A bit late to the post xD. Can you please share me the code in which you fetch the post from the users you're following? I've been trying to implement a feature like that in my app but I'm just unable to come up with the code lol.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a user model. And if you are using mongodb, you need to use mongoose.Schema. First you have to npm install mongoose. And then you need to create your user object like this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        //unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minLength: 1,
        required: true
    },
    name:{
        type: String,
       // unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minLength: 1,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        //unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minLength: 1,
        required: true,
        validate:{
            validator: validator.isEmail,
            message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email'
        }
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 4
    }
});
```

I suggest you look for some MEAN app tutorials for further help.

Comment: I have a User model. I am asking about efficient following between users. Check  my code at: [this repo](https://github.com/KidzGaming/Diode)