# mongdb ensure uniqueness on two fields both ways

Tags: mongodb, indexing, unique-index

Say I have the fields `a` and `b`. I want to have a compound uniqueness where if `a: 1, b: 2`, I would not be able to do `a: 2, b: 1`.

The reason I want this is because I'm making a "friends list" kind of collection, where if `a` is connected to `b`, then it's automatically the reverse as well.

is this possible on a schema level or do I need to do queries to check.

Comment: Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363220/modelling-for-friends-schema-in-mongoose

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I actually thought of another possible method (I'm still seeing if there's any documentation about this). I would simply create an array that holds 2 `ObjectIds`: the `requester` and `requestee` (order doesn't matter). Is it possible to make an index that ensures all values inside the array do not match another document? E.g. With `[1, 2]` already inserted, `[1, 3]` is legal, but `[2, 1]` is not

Comment: A.Lau May be there will be another way to do this but I don't think that there can be better way then this. And the point of uniqueness you can use `$addToSet` instead of `$push` in that answer. If you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet `$addToSet` is really just for single document uniqueness, not across multiple documents, nor the order. I will probably just use `$all` to ensure that the combination does not exist in the first place

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet wrote my current implementation attempt, though it doesn't use unique indexes.

Comment: If you don't need to differentiate between requester and requestee, you could sort the values before saving or querying so that your two fields `a` and `b` have a predictable order for any pair of friend IDs (and you can take advantage of a unique compound index on `a:1,b:1`).

Comment: @Stennie could you write a longer example so I can have a better look?

Comment: Added an example using the `mongo` shell. You could implement something similar using a driver or ODM.

Comment: Since you have a required `status` field in your $jsonSchema, I updated the findAndModify example to be more targeted and used `$setOnInsert` so the default status is `pending`.

Comment: Ok so your question is slightly different from my approach. You are asking for compound indexing  and I am answering  how friendship approach just like facebook does  can be done in a best way using mongodb and mongoose. You can either follow my answer or can go with the compound indexing. Choice is your's. **:-)**

Comment: @Stennie FIrstly I didn't get point of privacy here. Secondly why both the parties should accept because one of them will always be a requester and one is accepter. I will surely send you a app link once I completed it. **:-)**

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet On cursory glance I was thinking that [your model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363220/modelling-for-friends-schema-in-mongoose) in the related question provided separate relationship documents for the requester and recipient which might allow for more privacy (for example, allowing one person to quietly unfriend). However, that isn't really relevant.

Comment: @Stennie Could you suggest me  even better solution instead of that if possible? Because in my aspect it is probably the best way to define friendship model with mongoose and mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to differentiate between requester and requestee, you could sort the values before saving or querying so that your two fields `a` and `b` have a predictable order for any pair of friend IDs (and you can take advantage of the unique index constraint).

For example, using the `mongo` shell:

- Create a helper function to return friend pairs in predictable order:

  ```
  function friendpair (friend1, friend2) {
      if ( friend1 < friend2) {
          return ({a: friend1, b: friend2})
      } else {
          return ({a: friend2, b: friend1})      
      }
  }
  ```
- Add a compound unique index:

  ```
  > db.friends.createIndex({a:1, b:1}, {unique: true});
  {
      "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
      "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
      "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
      "ok" : 1
  }
  ```
- Insert unique pairs (should work)

  ```
  > db.friends.insert(friendpair(1,2))
  WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

  > db.friends.insert(friendpair(1,3))
  WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
  ```
- Insert non-unique pair (should return duplicate key error):

  ```
  > db.friends.insert(friendpair(2,1))
  WriteResult({
      "nInserted" : 0,
      "writeError" : {
          "code" : 11000,
          "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.friends index: a_1_b_1 dup key: { : 1.0, : 2.0 }"
      }
  })
  ```
- Search should work in either order:

  ```
  db.friends.find(friendpair(3,1)).pretty()
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5bc80ed11466009f3b56fa52"), "a" : 1, "b" : 3 }

  db.friends.find(friendpair(1,3)).pretty()
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5bc80ed11466009f3b56fa52"), "a" : 1, "b" : 3 }
  ```
- Instead of handling duplicate key errors or insert versus update, you could also use `findAndModify` with an `upsert` since this is expected to be a unique pair:

  ```
  > var pair = friendpair(2,1)
  > db.friends.findAndModify({
      query: pair,
      update: {
          $set: {
              a : pair.a,
              b : pair.b
          },
          $setOnInsert: { status: 'pending' },
      },
      upsert: true
  })

  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5bc81722ce51da0e4118c92f"),
      "a" : 1,
      "b" : 2,
      "status" : "pending"
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like you can do a unique on the entire array's values so I'm doing a kind of work around. I'm using the `$jsonSchema` as follows:

```
{
    $jsonSchema:
        {
            bsonType:
                "object",
            required:
                [
                    "status",
                    "users"
                ],
            properties:
                {
                    status:
                    {
                        enum:
                        [
                            "pending",
                            "accepted"
                        ],
                        bsonType:
                            "string"
                    },
                    users:
                        {
                            bsonType:
                                "array",
                            description:
                                "references two user_id",
                            items:
                                {
                                    bsonType:
                                        "objectId"
                                },
                            maxItems: 
                                2,
                            minItems: 
                                2,
                        },
                }
        }
}
```

then I will use `$all` to find the connected users, e.g.

```
db.collection.find( { users: { $all: [ ObjectId1, ObjectId2 ] } } )
```