# Embedding duplicate "friendship" subdocuments to model mutual friendship edges in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, graph-theory, data-modeling, social-networking

I'm trying to model bidirectional friendships in MongoDB. "Bidirectional" means, like Facebook but unlike Twitter, if you're friends with Sam then Sam must also be friends with you. In MongoDB, the usually-recommended solution ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50780844/126352)) seems to be to something like this:

- Create a `User` collection (aka nodes to use the proper graph theory term) and a `Friendship` collection (aka edges)
- Each `User` document contains an embedded `friends` array, each element of which contains the ObjectID of each friend.  Each element can also cache read-only info about each friend (e.g. name, photo URL) that can avoid cross-document queries for common use-cases like "display my friend list".
- Adding friendships involves inserting a new `Friendship` document and then `$push`-ing the `Friendship`'s Object ID into a `friends` array in both users, as well as read-only cached info about friends (e.g. name) to avoid multi-document queries when displaying friend lists.

I'm considering a different design where, instead of a separate `Friendship` collection, edge data will be stored (duplicated) in both nodes of the bidirectional relationship.  Like this:

```json
  {
    _id: new ObjectID("111111111111111111111111"),
    name: "Joe", 
    pictureUrl: "https://foo.com/joe.jpg",
    invites: [
      ... // similar schema to friends array below
    ],
    friends: [
      {
        friendshipId: new ObjectID("123456789012345678901234"),
        lastMeeting: new Date("2019-02-07T20:35:55.256+00:00"),
        user1: {
          userId: new ObjectID("111111111111111111111111"),
          name: "Joe",  // cached, read-only data to avoid multi-doc reads
          pictureUrl: "https://foo.com/joe.jpg",
        },
        user2: {
          userId: new ObjectID("222222222222222222222222"),
          name: "Bill",  // cached, read-only data to avoid multi-doc reads
          pictureUrl: "https://foo.com/bill.jpg",
        },
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectID("222222222222222222222222"),
    name: "Bill",
    pictureUrl: "https://foo.com/bill.jpg",
    invites: [
      ... // similar schema to friends array below
    ],
    friends: [
      {
        friendshipId: new ObjectID("123456789012345678901234"),
        lastMeeting: new Date("2019-02-07T20:35:55.256+00:00"), // shared data about the edge
        user1: {  // data specific to each friend
          userId: new ObjectID("111111111111111111111111"),
          name: "Joe",  // cached, read-only data to avoid multi-doc reads
          pictureUrl: "https://foo.com/joe.jpg",
        },
        user2: { // data specific to each friend
          userId: new ObjectID("222222222222222222222222"),
          name: "Bill",  // cached, read-only data to avoid multi-doc reads
          pictureUrl: "https://foo.com/bill.jpg",
        },
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here's how I'm planning to deal with the following:

- Reads - all reads for common operations happen only from individual `User` documents. High-level info about friends (e.g. name, picture URL) are cached inside the `friends` array.
- Inviting a friend - add a new document to an `invites` array embedded into both users (not shown above) that's similar in structure and functionality to the `friends` collection shown above
- Invitation accepted - using `updateMany`, add a new identical embedded document to the `friends` array of both users, and `$pull` an element from `invites` array of both users. Initially I'll use multi-document transactions for these updates, but because adding friendships isn't time-critical, this could be adapted to use eventual consistency.
- Friendship revoked - use `updateMany` with a filter for `{'friends.friendshipId': new ObjectID("123456789012345678901234")}` to `$pull` the friendship subdocument from both users' `friends` arrays.  Like above, this could use multi-document transactions initially, and eventual consistency later if needed for scale.
- Updates to cached data - if a user changes info cached in `friends` (e.g. name or picture URL), this is an uncommon operation that can proceed slowly and one-document-at-a-time, so eventual consistency is fine.

I have two basic concerns that I'd like your advice about:

- What are the problems and pitfalls with the approach described above?  I know about the obvious things: extra storage, slower updates, need to add queuing and retry logic to support eventual consistency, and the risk of edge data getting out-of-sync between its two copies. I think I'm OK with these problems. But are there other, non-obvious problems that I will likely run into?
- Instead of having a `user1` and `user2` field for each node of the edge, would it be better to use a 2-element array instead?  Why or why not?  Here's an example of what I mean:

  ```
  friends: [
    {
      friendshipId: new ObjectID("123456789012345678901234"),
      lastMeeting: new Date("2019-02-07T20:35:55.256+00:00"),
      users: [
        {
          userId: new ObjectID("111111111111111111111111"),
          name: "Joe",  // cached, read-only data to avoid multi-doc reads
          pictureUrl: "https://foo.com/joe.jpg",
        },
        {
          userId: new ObjectID("222222222222222222222222"),
          name: "Bill",  // cached, read-only data to avoid multi-doc reads
          pictureUrl: "https://foo.com/bill.jpg",
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
  ```

BTW, I know that graph databases and even relational databases are better at modeling relationships compared to MongoDB. But for a variety of reasons I've settled on MongoDB for now, so please limit answers to MongoDB solutions rather than pointing me to using a graph or relational database. Thanks!

Comment: r.e. arrays vs. keyed objects -- arrays are almost always the way to go in mongo. If you're ever querying by  fields in that users array, you can use a single multikey index, rather than doing an $or query and creating two indexes.

Comment: @willis - does that mean that the limitation on array-valued multi-key indexes doesn't apply to navigating *through* arrays to get to the (non-array) values that would be indexed inside `friends.users` (e.g. `friends.users.name`), given that both `friends` and `users` are arrays?

Comment: Oh, shoot -- I didn't catch that `users` was nested within `friends`. So, using `user1` and `user2` like you said _would_ allow you to have indexes on those fields and using arrays would not.

Comment: So basically you need best approach for friendship modelling with mongodb?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet - Yes, with the caveat that I'm on MongoDB 4.0 so I can take advantage of multi-document transactions and other features added in the last few years. Looking at similar questions (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mongodb+friendship) most of them are 3+ years old and seem to be focused on dealing with the problem of atomic updates or are trying to make relational models work on MongoDB instead of thinking about the problem in a Mongo-specific way.

Comment: Well I have something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363220/modelling-for-friends-schema-in-mongoose/50780844#50780844

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet - yep, I linked to that solution in my question. What I'm wondering is whether I can avoid having a separate "Friends" collection. Given that I have to update both users anyways when a friendship is established, I'm not sure what benefit there is in having a separate collection for the edge, as opposed to just cloning the edge data in both User documents.