# Want to implement "friend connect request" in React Project, don't know how to design MongoDB Model

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

When I am working on my React social media project, I want to add a "Friend connect request" feature. I use MongoDB, and here is my "User Model" below.

Now my "Friends" is nested inside `UserSchema`, but feels like this is not right.

1. What if I want more stats, for example `pending, rejected, block sender...`
2. Let's say: User A sent connect request to B, then B should know, and when B try to send out requests to friends, A should be excluded.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'User Name is required'],
        lowercase: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Email or Phone number is required'],
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Password is required'], 
    },
    thumbnail: {
        type: String,
        default: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/09/17/52/instagram-1581266_960_720.jpg',
    },
    createAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
    friends: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user',
        }
    ], 
}),
```

I am newbee, first time meet this kind of question, and don't know the design logic behind this feature. Could anyone has experience give me some advances (welcome all of frontend and backend, database design)?

Comment: Have you considered adding a `FriendRequest` model to represent pending requests? Could indicate the sender and recipient, when it was sent, whether it's been seen/accepted/rejected, and so on. You could then filter based on the existence and status of request instances.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean separate Friend out from UserSchema? Or keep Friend nested inside User, but add extra `FriendRequest` schema? Could you give me more details?

Comment: May be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363220/modelling-for-friends-schema-in-mongoose

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion on whether to move `friends` out of your UserSchema. Seems fine where it is unless there's a specific problematic use case. I'd suggest adding—or at least considering—a `FriendRequest` schema as a separate model.

Comment: Wooo! Thank you @rayhatfield, Save my day!

Comment: Thank you  @Anthony Winzlet! This this a really good one.