# Mongoose Friend Request model aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working on a social-media type project and we decided to have a create a separate model to store friend requests. It goes something like this:

```
const Friendship = new mongoose.Schema({
  users: [{IDref for User1}, {IDref for User2}],
  accepted: []//this will store both user IDs if the friendship is reciprocal and only 1 if its not 
})
```

Now, I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but its giving me trouble when I want to include an user's friends on the User model.

From what I've read on the docs `virtual` doesn't support searching in arrays, and I'm not sure on how to use the `aggregator`pipeline

Any help would be welcomed

Comment: You can take reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363220/modelling-for-friends-schema-in-mongoose)

Comment: @Ashh I did see that post, and that's why I'm asking about aggregator pipelines, because it seems like it is the only way to do it but I don't really undertand what is going on